# PHP: Work out duration between two times

Tags: php

Ok, a really simple question but I am too thick to figure it out. I want to get the difference between two times. For example, "1:07" (1 minute and 7 seconds) and "3:01" (3 minutes and 1 second). It will only be ever minutes and seconds. I have been trying to make use of this:

```
function timeDiff($firstTime,$lastTime)
{

// convert to unix timestamps
$firstTime=strtotime($firstTime);
$lastTime=strtotime($lastTime);

// perform subtraction to get the difference (in seconds) between times
$timeDiff=$lastTime-$firstTime;

// return the difference
return $timeDiff;
}
```

But I think I am running in the wrong direction?

Thank you for any help.

### EDIT

I tried this: echo timeDiff('1:07','2:30');

I got this output "4980"

What is the above? Is it seconds? I have no idea how to get it as "1:23" which is the difference.

### EDIT 2

Thank you all, I learnt so much just from this one thread, esp. Paul's. It works very well and I like the defensiveness!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You can't use strtotime as it will interpret MM:SS as HH:MM** - that's why you are getting higher values than expected.

You could simply prepend your MM:SS values with '00:' to make them look like HH:MM:SS.

*Note however that strtotime, if just given HH:MM:SS, will give a timestamp for **today**, which is fine for throwaway code. Don't use that technique for anything important, consider what happens if your two calls to strtotime straddle midnight!*

Alternatively, something like this will turn a MM:SS value into a timestamp you can do arithmetic on

```
function MinSecToSeconds($minsec)
{
    if (preg_match('/^(\d+):(\d+)$/', $minsec, $matches))
    {
        return $matches[1]*60 + $matches[2];
    }
    else
    {
        trigger_error("MinSecToSeconds: Bad time format $minsec", E_USER_ERROR);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It's a little more defensive than using explode, but shows another approach!

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly. In case anyone needs it in the future, maybe you should an extra right bracket for the if function. :)

Answer (score 6):

This should give you the difference between the two times in seconds.

```
$firstTime = '1:07';
$secondTime = '3:01';

list($firstMinutes, $firstSeconds) = explode(':', $firstTime);
list($secondMinutes, $secondSeconds) = explode(':', $secondTime);

$firstSeconds += ($firstMinutes * 60);
$secondSeconds += ($secondMinutes * 60);
$difference = $secondSeconds - $firstSeconds;
```

Answer (score 3):

Using code found [here][1], how about calculating the seconds yourself:

```
<?php

function time_to_sec($time) {
    $hours = substr($time, 0, -6);
    $minutes = substr($time, -5, 2);
    $seconds = substr($time, -2);

    return $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
}

function sec_to_time($seconds) {
    $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
    $minutes = floor($seconds % 3600 / 60);
    $seconds = $seconds % 60;

    return sprintf("%d:%02d:%02d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
} 


function timeDiff($firstTime,$lastTime)
{

// convert to seconds
$firstTime=time_to_sec($firstTime);
$lastTime=time_to_sec($lastTime);

// perform subtraction to get the difference (in seconds) between times
$timeDiff=$lastTime-$firstTime;

// return the difference
return sec_to_time($timeDiff);
}

echo timeDiff("1:07", "3:01");


?>
```

returns 0:01:54
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php#86589

Answer (score 3):

The strtotime function is for converting **dates (down to the second)** in a string format into a Unix Timestamp style format.  It is NOT for converting strings in a time format into anything.  See if these two statments help your undersatnding any

```
//recent php5 for DATE_RFC822
echo date(DATE_RFC822,strtotime('1:07'));
echo date(DATE_RFC822,strtotime('3:01'));
```

It sounds like you want something like this

```
function timeDiff($firstTime,$lastTime)
{
    //split minutes and seconds
    list($min_one, $sec_one) = preg_split('{:}',$firstTime,2, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    list($min_two, $sec_two) = preg_split('{:}',$lastTime ,2, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    //convert times into seconds
    $time_one = $min_one * 60 + $sec_one;
    $time_two = $min_two * 60 + $sec_two;

    //return times
    return $time_two - $time_one;
}

echo timeDiff('1:07','3:10');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$time1 = date("H:i",strtotime($strtime));
$time2 = date("H:i");
list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time1);
$startTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes);

list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time2);
$endTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes);

$seconds = $endTimestamp - $startTimestamp;
$minutes = ($seconds / 60) % 60;
$hours = floor($seconds / (60 * 60));
```